# Neo4j browser and some databse queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

what is the difference between remote and a local graph in neo4j browser. I have searched an answer for this question but didn't get any so please help me .

thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is asking about the options in the Neo4j Desktop.

A local graph is one you create on the same machine that is running the Neo4j Desktop application.

A remote instance is a Neo4j instance that resides on a different machine, so you need to supply the connection information so a bolt connection can be made so you access the instance.

Comment: thank you for the answer but could you elaborate on the remote instance?

Comment: Local instance - on your machine. Remote instance - on a different machine and you need the IP of it to connect via the browser. You can't create a remote instance via the Desktop app, you're just connecting to some existing instance that was previously set up. It may help to provide specific questions of what you want to know about this.

Comment: thanks, do have any idea on how to connect with neo4j using jdbc driver, i cant seem to access the driver file .can u provide me with an example.

Comment: You should start with the [official documentation for driver usage](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/get-started/).